# Parsing and modifying a powershell object

Tags: powershell, object, match

I'm parsing HTML from a webserver (specifically a Fanuc controller) and assigning the `innerText` to a object.

```
#Make sure the controller respons
if ($webBody.StatusCode -eq 200) {
    Write-Host "Response is Good!" -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
    $preBody = $webBody.ParsedHtml.body.getElementsByTagName('PRE') | Select -ExpandProperty innerText
    $preBody
}
```

The output looks a little like so:

```
  [1-184 above]
  [185] = 0  ''   
  [186] = 0  ''   
  [187] = 0  ''   
  [188] = 0  ''   
  [189] = 0  '' 
  [and so on]
```

I only want to read the data from 190, 191, 193 for example. 
What's the best way to do this? I'm struggling to sanitize the unwanted data in the object.

Currently I have a vbscript app that outputs to a txt file, cleans the data then reads it back and manipulates it in to a sql insert. I'm trying to improve on it with powershell and keen to try and keep everything within the program if possible.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

With the assumption that the data set is not too large to place everything into memory. You could parse with regex into a PowerShell Object, then you can use `Where-Object` to filter.

```
#Regex with a capture group for each important value
$RegEx = "\[(.*)\]\s=\s(\d+)\s+'(.*)'"
$IndexesToMatch = @(190, 191, 193)
$ParsedValues = $prebody.trim | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        index = $_ -replace $regex,'$1'
        int = $_ -replace $regex,'$2'
        string = $_ -replace $regex,'$3'
    } 
}
$ParsedValues | Where-Object { $_.index -in $IndexesToMatch }
```

Input :

```
[190] = 1  'a'
[191] = 2  'b'
[192] = 3  'c'
[193] = 4  'd'
[194] = 5  'e'
```

Output :

```
index int string
----- --- ------
190   1   a
191   2   b
193   4   d
```

Comment: Thanks for showing this, i never thought of using a replace withing a custom object before. Going to bookmark this for future reference.